# How to make relationship using the value of the properties using neo4j

Tags: neo4j, nosql, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

How to make relationship using the value of the properties

Example: There is dataset imported named customers, its node label is `CUSTOMER` and it has big amount of data:

```
 id, mobile number, city, contact type, date
```

[Customer data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GxQ7.png)

There is an another data set name `calllog` details, its node label is log and the properties are Duration, event date, Incoming calls, outgoing calls

[call logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwFbc.png)

**Note**: the values of the **INCOMING** numbers in LOG node are also present in MOBILE number values of the CUSTOMER node .

How can i build a relation to `CUSTOMER {Mobile 'Value'} == to CALL LOG (incoming number 'Value')`

```
mobile no:'07123456'  == incoming number : '07123456'
```

the customer data base (mobile number) contains same value of the call log data base (Incoming calls)

I want to join them using neo4j

IMAGE 3
[IMAGE3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIBqW.png)
how can I do this explain with code  thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (log:Log)
WITH log
MATCH (cust:Customer)
WHERE cust.mob=log.incomming
CREATE (log)-[:MYNEWRELATIONTYPE]->(cust)
```

Comment: The nodes are customer & log  node

Comment: Table
Code
(no changes, no records)   this appeared  can i have an email so i can sen screen shots

Comment: please look the image 3

Comment: I saw the labels on the previous screen shots. If you are more clear in your comments, you may actually get some help here. For instance, explaining what works / does not work with my snippet. Reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask may also help ;)